# Populate a field with value from another field based on xpaths using javascript

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript

I'm trying to read a value from a dynamic text field (value is updated on each visit) based on the xpath and pass it in the field below.

The page validation is the match between those two fields based on the second xpath.

I tried something like  `value="document.getElementsByClassName('Class_1_Field_Name')">//*[@data-testid='Id_Name_field2']`

Any idea how I should proceed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to read the value of the first field based on its XPath, and then populate the second field with that value based on its XPath. Here's an example code snippet:

```
// Find the first field element using its XPath
var field1 = document.evaluate("XPATH_OF_FIELD_1", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

// Read the value of the first field
var value1 = field1.value;

// Find the second field element using its XPath
var field2 = document.evaluate("XPATH_OF_FIELD_2", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

// Set the value of the second field to the value of the first field
field2.value = value1;
```

You can replace the XPATH_OF_FIELD_1 and XPATH_OF_FIELD_2 with the actual XPath values for your fields. You can execute this JavaScript code in the browser console or using Selenium's `execute_script()` method. Here's an example using Selenium WebDriver in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Launch the browser and navigate to the page
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://example.com")

# Execute the JavaScript code to populate the fields
driver.execute_script("""
    var field1 = document.evaluate("XPATH_OF_FIELD_1", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    var value1 = field1.value;
    var field2 = document.evaluate("XPATH_OF_FIELD_2", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    field2.value = value1;
""")
```

Replace the XPATH_OF_FIELD_1 and XPATH_OF_FIELD_2 with your actual XPath values.